# Getting a child element's ID onClick when using bypassSecurityTrustHtml Pipes

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

How do you capture a child element's ID on click from the parent element? I have a view that uses a pipe to convert hashtags and @ mentions into bold colorful text. This transformation is done within a pipe class.

The component template has the following line:

```html
<div class="feed-card-text-body" id="textBody" (click)="tagClick() [innerHTML]="post.body|tagify"></div>
```

Which results to something like this:

```html
<div _ngcontent-rjl-c108="" class="feed-card-text-body" id="textBody" (click)="tagClick()>
    This is my testing post.
    <span id="#hashtags" style="font-weight: bolder; color: var(--navy);">#hashtags</span>
    <span id="#WootWoot" style="font-weight: bolder; color: var(--navy);">#WootWoot</span>. 
    <span id="@membername" style="font-weight: bolder; color: var(--purple-95);">@membername</span>
</div>
```

Everything displays as it should, but I would like the click event `tagClick()` to capture the child `span` ID. For example if someone taps on the `#hashtags` span, I'd like the click event to return the ID of that span.

This is easily solved through the template in most situations by attaching the click event to the actual element, however, since it's being processed by a pipe I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straight forward. In Angular, the `(click)` binding, when including `$event` in the method parameter, will provide the clicked element's object data. So modifying the `tagClick()` to `tagClick($event)` is the only template change that needs to be made.

```html
<div _ngcontent-rjl-c108="" class="feed-card-text-body" id="textBody" (click)="tagClick($event)>
    This is my testing post.
    <span id="tag_hashtags" style="font-weight: bolder; color: var(--navy);">#hashtags</span>
    <span id="tag_WootWoot" style="font-weight: bolder; color: var(--navy);">#WootWoot</span>. 
    <span id="at_membername" style="font-weight: bolder; color: var(--purple-95);">@membername</span>
</div>
```

Then change the `tagClick()` method to `tagClick(event)` in the component class. This will allow you to access the clicked element's object data through the `event.target` object as so:

```ts
tagClick(event): void {
  const id = event.target.id;
  const atRegex = /^at_/gi;
  const tagRegex = /^tag_/gi;

  if (atRegex.test(id)) {
    console.log('Mentioned ' + id.replace('at_', '@'));
  }
  if (tagRegex.test(id)) {
      console.log('Hashtag ' + id.replace('tag_', '#'));
  }
}
```